# Create Shapely Polygon around labelled coordinates

Tags: pandas, polygon, point, geopandas, shapely

I have a pandas dataframe of buildings in a city. The buildings have a latitude and longitude column and are grouped into separate management locations.

I've managed to create a geopandas dataframe with a 'geometry' column of shapely Points for each building and plot those on a map with separate colour for each management location. However is there a way to group the geodataframe by management location and have the 'geometry' column as a shapely Polygon encompassing the points corresponding to each building within each management location?

I currently have:

```
geo_poly['geometry'] = geo_poly['geometry'].apply(lambda x: x.coords[0])
geo_poly = geo_poly.groupby('management location')['geometry'].apply(lambda x: Polygon(x.tolist())).reset_index()
geo_poly = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geo_poly, geometry = 'geometry')
```

But when I plot it:

```
geo_poly.plot(ax = ax)
```

It has obviously drawn a polygon by traversing each point in the geopandas dataframe.

[image: plot of polygons]

I would have thought geopandas would have (or there would exist somewhere) a better way to draw a polygon around the points at the edge of a defined cluster but I'm having difficulty finding one.

Any help would be gratefully received,
Thanks

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly... you want a polygon which encloses all the points of a single "management location"? I think you're looking for a convex hull: https://geopandas.org/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.convex_hull.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the GeoDataFrame's `dissolve` function to "fuse" all the points in the groups and then use the `convex_hull` attribute to extract the polygon surrounding all the grouped/fused/dissolved points.

Here's a small reproducible example:

```py
# Importing libraries used
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely

# Setting the random seed
np.random.seed(6)

# Determining the number of points in the example
npoints = 15

# Generating the GeoDataFrame with random Points
mydf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'id':range(npoints),
                         'geometry':(pd.Series(list(np.random.rand(npoints,2)))
                                     .apply(shapely.geometry.Point)),
                         'group':np.random.randint(1,3,npoints)})

# Plotting the GeoDataFrame according to the "group" column
mydf.plot(column='group', cmap='Set1')

# Fusing all of the Points based on the "group" column and 
# generating a Polygon that envelops all of the Points in
# each group
new_df = (mydf.dissolve(by='group')
          .convex_hull
          .reset_index()
          .rename({0:'geometry'},axis=1))

# Plotting the original Point and the newly-generated Polygons
ax = new_df.plot(column='group',cmap='tab20c', alpha=.7)
mydf.plot(ax = ax, column='group', cmap='Set1')
```

Here is the plot of the original points by group:

[image: Points colored by group]

And here is the plot of the polygons that enclose the point groups:

[image: Polygons enclosing each group's points]

So, for your specific example, you could do something like this:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point

# Creating a new column with Point geometries
geo_poly['geometry_pt'] = geo_poly['geometry'].apply(lambda x: Point(x.coords[0]))

# Transforming into a GeoDataFrame
geo_poly = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geo_poly, geometry = 'geometry_pt')

# Dissolving and extracting the new Polygons
new_geo_poly = (geo_poly.dissolve(by='management location')
                .convex_hull
                .reset_index()
                .rename({0:'geometry'},axis=1))
```

You might have to tweak that line regarding the creation of the new "geometry_pt" column. But once you get that fixed, the rest should work =)

Comment: Thanks Felipe. I take it this is similar to pandas groupby? So in the example above you gave the resultant dataframe will be 3 rows each with a separate polygon as geometry?

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, `dissolve` is similar to `groupby`. The `new_df` object is a GeoDataFrame with polygons that "envelop" all of the points in the group. You can switch the 'group' column to your 'management location' column and it will do exactly what you want. 

I've added comments and more commands to ensure that the output is a new `GeoDataFrame`. I've also added commands that add colors to the plots to make it easier to visualize what's happening. 

PS: There will only be 2 groups in the ex: `randint(1,3)` will only generate 1's and 2's (i.e., the upper limit is excluded)

Comment: By the way, if my post answers your original question, please consider "accepting" the answer by clicking the check-mark on the left. Thanks!

Comment: There, I've also added some images to help visualize what's going on =)